# how can i return an array

Tags: php

how can i return an array like :

```
$array = array(
       1 => array('id' => '12','name' => 'Great man'),
       2 => array('id' => '14','name' => 'Lamborgini'),
       3 => array('id' => '29','name' => 'Leon'), 
   );
```

please attention to first keys

Comment: [You got it right](http://codepad.org/HpWeK0k6), what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just return $array, it already holds the right values.  There's nothing in PHP stopping you from returning data of any type you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can use arrays in php like any other variable:

```
function return_an_array() {
  return array(
       1 => array('id' => '12','name' => 'Great man'),
       2 => array('id' => '14','name' => 'Lamborgini'),
       3 => array('id' => '29','name' => 'Leon'), 
   );
}

$my_array = return_an_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $array like any PHP var.

e.g.:

```
foreach($array as $value)
{
    // now use $value['id'] or $value['name'];
    // sample:
    echo 'ID: '.$value['id'].'<br/>';
    echo 'NAME: '.$value['name'].'<br/>';
}
```

and

```
$great_man = $array[1];
echo 'id: '.$great_man['id'].' name: '.$great_man['name'];
```

Comment: What does this have to do with returning an array?

Comment: Then come on BoltClock, answer his question.. function return_array() { global $array; return $array; } -.-

Answer (score 0):

When you say return an array, I think you might mean access an array?

```
$array = array(
  1 => array('id' => '12','name' => 'Great man'),
  2 => array('id' => '14','name' => 'Lamborgini'),
  3 => array('id' => '29','name' => 'Leon'), 
);

echo $array[1]['id']; // 12
echo $array[1]['name']; // Great Man
echo $array[3]['name']; // Leon
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what the OP is wanting, is to use the **id** of each element as the key. A simple enough thing to achieve.

So, instead of your original code of:

```
$array = array(
       1 => array('id' => '12','name' => 'Great man'),
       2 => array('id' => '14','name' => 'Lamborgini'),
       3 => array('id' => '29','name' => 'Leon'), 
   );
```

You would simply use:

```
$array = array(
       12 => 'Great man' ,
       14 => 'Lamborgini' ,
       29 => 'Leon'
   );
```

NOTE: The Array Keys do not have to be sequential, but they do need to be unique, within that array. They can also be either integers or strings.